# ASP.NET Serenity Framework Template Change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have to change the dialog box type and the default table view to a particular bootstrap template. Is it possible for me to change it in ASP.NET Serenity MVC Framework? Most of the html visual parts are script based in Serene framework. Is it possible to change the serene default visual template? if it is possible, then please give me some instruction about it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit LESS files.

A quote from its original tutorial:

> We are using LESS for CSS generation so you should try editing LESS files, not CSS. Next time you build your project, LESS files will be compiled to CSS (using Less.js compiler for Node).

More information on theming: https://volkanceylan.gitbooks.io/serenity-guide/serene_tour/theming.html